# Replicate the Google+ drop down buttons/boxes

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I want to make a Google-style drop down box, style and everything. I mean this type of drop down box:

[image: dropdown]

As you can see the basic `<select>` isn't that nice:

[image: dropdown]

I tried using Chrome Dev Tools on Gmail but is it nearly impossible because when you click onto Dev tools the drop down box goes away.

Does anyone have any idea on how to replicate these or are there any tutorials online already (or even better - a jQuery plugin)?

I've searched Google a lot for it but I just keep getting the drop down menu tutorials.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And I'm guessing the downvote is for...?

Comment: Two tricks in Chrome dev tools for inspecting. First, undock the console (lowest left icon). Position the window over the drop down. Then right click -> inspect element. The console will popup and leave the menu in the descended state. Second, on top right hand side there is a `toggle element state` icon. You can select to show the 'hover' state of elements.

Comment: It'd have to be converted to a DIV to style the options box. Something like this may be suitable for you: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/reinventing-drop-down/#

Comment: Maybe give some clarification on the things you're not certain how to do. CSS can be used to style both menu elements and form elements, and achieving that look should be pretty easy if you know your way around CSS.

Comment: @mrtsherman Wow, I did not know that. I was always frustrated with finding the states of an element. Thanks for those tips!

Comment: Love this: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-selectBox/

Comment: @user1090389 Thanks for all of these links. The first and last one I really like. I don't feel that the "glossiness" of the jQuery UI drop down box will go good with the website that I'm making.

Comment: @mrtsherman Sadly, Gmail made it really difficult and they don't use element states. They change classes for everything. (hover, focus, etc.) which makes it really hard to get it because even when you unfocus the window it goes away. I'll probably just end up using [this](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/reinventing-drop-down/Select2DropDown.html) and add my own style or [this](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-selectBox/).

Comment: @user1090389 Post your comments as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Any chance of you sharing what you finally made? It looks great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd have to be converted to a DIV to style the options box. Something like this may be suitable for you: http://jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/reinventing-drop-down/#

Love this: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-selectBox

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wanted to let you know that I recreated it myself, and it looks and functions just like it now: http://screencast.com/t/Wq5DPnksJr6

Comment: Thank you :) It took a while to get it figured out but I got it to work finally. I might make it into a jQuery plugin someday.